# firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount do not change even Scroll event happened

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview

Im having a ScrollView which contains a Listview, However even if I scroll the listview, the three parameters in onscroll() method do not change, they remain the same as the initial state.

Here's my layout

[image]

Also my code for handling the scroll event,noted the **contentlist**  is the listview not the scrollview.

[image]

However as you can see in the logcat, nothing change even if i scroll around and the visible item count should be **two** only

[image]

[image]

**I wonder if its because of the height of the listview which cause this issue?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView` always cause problems.. Why don't you just have the `ListView` in the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and use [`addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) to display your `LinearLayout` above it?

Comment: thanks bro, you are right, put list view inside a scrollview did cause issues/